# Installing Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

It looks like the Microsoft is no supporting the free download of infopath 2010.
I am working in Sharepoint 2010 and would like to create customized list form using infopath. I downloaded infopath 2013, but it doesnt seem to work with lists in share-point 2010.

where is the link to download infopath 2010? or  is it no more free?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. If you had done so, you would know that the guidelines in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly say this type of question is off-topic here. Please do that reading before asking your next question here.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with Office.
You can try to get it with your license key on:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/office